# AttributeError on check whether RandomForestClassifier has been initialised

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a class that holds a scikitlearn-RandomForestClassifier as a member variable.
In the `__init__`-method, it is first initialised to None,

```
def __init__(self):
   self.classifier = None
```

and
later, once all necessary parameters are available, a `RandomForestClassifier` is created and
assigned to this member variable:

```
def init_classifier(self):
    self.classifier = RandomForestClassifier(**params)
```

(In the debugger I can see that `self.classifier` has been initialised to something meaningful.)
In the class method that is supposed to fit the classifier to the data, it is first checked whether
the classifier has been initialised already:

```
if not self.classifier:
    self.init_classifier()
```

This results in an `AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'.`
If the check is done by comparing to None explicitly,

```
if self.classifier is None:
    self.init_classifier()
```

it runs through. Can someone explain to me where this AttributeError comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why this behavior, you need to look at how the boolean comparison of an object works in Python. (i.e when you call `if A`).

1. First, the interpreter will try to see if the object implements the [special method `__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__). This a special method that will either return `True` or `False`.
2. If the `__bool__` special method is not defined, then the interpreter will try to use the `__len__` function. If the result is 0, then the expression is evaluated at `False`. *This is where the exception comes from*.
3. If the `__len__` function is not defined either, then the statement is evaluated to `True`.

If we look at the [`BaseEnsemble` class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py#L81) from which inherits `RandomForestClassifier`, we can see that it does not implement a `__bool__` special method, but does implement a `__len__` special method :

```
def __len__(self):
    """Return the number of estimators in the ensemble."""
    return len(self.estimators_)
```

So when you are calling `if not self.classifier:`, you are calling that `__len__` function. At the moment in your code, the `RandomForestClassifier` is not yet properly instantiated *(this is my guess)* and does not have the `estimators_` attribute, hence the exception.

If you want to check that an object is not instantiated, always explicitly call the comparison to `None`. In that case, the interpreter will check the object against `None`.